# How to get the interface I am connected to

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets, getaddrinfo, select-function

I am trying to implement an application which receives a packet(ICMP maybe) on a tap interface. I have the code something like this.

```
strcpy(ifName, "tap0");
if ((sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW,0) == -1) {
    perror("ERROR: socket");    
}
retVal = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,
                        (char *)&sockopt, sizeof(sockopt)); // int sockopt

setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_BINDTODEVICE, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
max_sd = sockfd;
FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
// Similarly I have other fd's for tap1 and tap2 set to this &readfds

timeout.tv_sec  = 30;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

retVal = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL,NULL,&timeout);

if(retVal == 1){
    // Now I know I got some message on one of the tap interface. How do I find out which
one ??
}
```

TWO QUESTIONS :

1. Now once I receive something on select, how  do I find out on which tap interface did the packet arrive ?
2. Also how can I test this code. I have these interface UP , how do I inject packets so that this receive function will work ? Can someone give the command ? ping should work(it sends ICMP packet). What is the correct command. I tried "ping -I tap0 localhost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list of fd"s saved.  Just a sample code

```
 // say you have 5 fd save in FD[] // have a mapping from fd's to tap interfaces
 // fd[1] -- tap1
 //fd[2] -- tap2 something like this
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   if(FD_ISSET(fd[i],&readfd)){
     //you have the fd, look up corresponding interface
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find out at which adapter (or interface) a packet arrive with one socket.

Set up one socket per interface and receive with both sockets.

Answer (score 0):

you need to open `multiple sockets`, one for each interface. the packet received on one interface will not be seen on any other interface. :)

There are separate `RecvQ/TransQ` for each Interface.

Comment: Then how can I listen on multiple interfaces at the same time. I thought that is why we use select in the first place .

Comment: `select` is to facilitate the `read/write ready` file descriptor detection. basically you don't have to block on the `FDs`